# update an entire column from another database table to current database table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, datatables, insert-update

I am trying to update a column in a table of one database to other table in a different database. Here is my query:

```
update mr set reqprofile_id=subhamastu.response_to from matrimonyrequests mr INNER JOIN subhamastu.matrimony_response smr ON mr.reqid=smr.matrimony_response_id;
```

I am getting "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from matrimonyrequests mr INNER JOIN subhamastu.matrimony_response smr ON mr.req' at line 1"

I have tried the above query. Actually i want to update a column which matches a table column email id to a table called register and get profileid and update in
my table. I am attaching a structure of two databases.[image]

I want to update the column in requesttable from 'old' database responsetable column response_to, however, i want to put the profileid that matches the email in response table in new database requesttable. Quite difficult to explain. I don't know i conveyed my message correctly or not. So attached the structure of the image. Hope somebody helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct MySQL syntax is:

```
update matrimonyrequests mr INNER JOIN
       subhamastu.matrimony_response smr 
       ON mr.reqid=smr.matrimony_response_id
    set reqprofile_id = subhamastu.response_to ;
```

Your syntax looked more like SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I want to get profileid from register table from different database and update in matrimonyrequests table. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: @amardeep . . . New questions should be asked as new questions and not in a comment.

Comment: It's not a new question. I already mentioned it above. I have posted the query which i have tried, that didn't worked.
     update matrimonyrequests mr INNER JOIN subhamastu.matrimony_response smr ON mr.reqid=smr.matrimony_response_id set reqprofile_id = (select sr.profile_id from subhamastu.matrimony_response smr left join subhamastu.register sr on smr.response_to=sr.lemail);
       The above is the query which I have tried.

Comment: This one worked for me:
     update matrimonyrequests mr LEFT JOIN
       subhamastu.matrimony_response smr
       ON mr.reqid=smr.matrimony_response_id
       LEFT JOIN subhamastu.register r
       ON smr.response_to=r.lemail
    set reqprofile_id = r.profile_id;